# What is the format(type) of the refresh token in firebase

Tags: firebase

In the firebase I got a access token and a refresh token. I there the access token (token ID) is a JWT token, but the refresh token is not a JWT token and it's an opaque string token. I want to know what the format is that firebase use to generate this refresh token.

I want to know what the format is that firebase use to generate this refresh token.

Comment: You should probably update your question to say what your purpose is for this token that requires you to know more than you already do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the article [Demystifying Firebase Auth Tokens](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c) by a former Firebase team member:

> The refresh token is a standard OAuth 2.0 refresh token, which you can learn more about [here](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens).